# Taking really long to compile my C++ code

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-optimization

I have a really long initializer list, something like this.

```
 std::vector<Inventory> inventory_list = {Inventory(0,30.0),
    Inventory(1,30.0),
    Inventory(2,30.0),
    Inventory(3,30.0),
    Inventory(4,30.0),
    Inventory(5,30.0),
    Inventory(29,30.0),
    Inventory(30,30.0),}

 .....
```

having around 72000 lines of such initializer list and its already taken over half hour and still compiling. Is there a way to make this faster? Or is this something that s expected for such large amount of data?

Comment: Poor compiler, having to go through these 72,000 lines, without a break for half an hour... Please end its suffering.

Comment: Why not loading such a large initialization list from a file with a for loop instead? Also, which compiler are you using?

Comment: Couldn't you write a simple loop to populate the datastructure? Or load the data from a file at run-time?

Comment: By chance is `inventory_list`  a **global** variable that you are initializing in the global namespace (and not within a function body)?

Comment: Yeah, i think loading it in run time is the way to go.

Comment: @selbie Its doing within the function body.

Comment: What purpose does this thing serve? Why can't this be stored in something more convenient like a binary file, a CSV/JSON/YAML/XML file or a database like [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html)?

Comment: Since there is no mixed mode debugging for Python/C++ on my Mac, i am writing out a dataframe from python to a file and creating a test case so that I can debug the C++ code independently.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as a workaround:

```
struct InitData
{
    int i;
    double v;
};

InitData init[] = { {1,30.0}, {2,30.0}, {3,30.0}, {4,30.0}, {5,30.0}, ...};

std::vector<Inventory> inventory_list;
size_t count = sizeof(init) / sizeof(init[0]);
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
     inventory_list.push_back(Inventory(init[i].i, init[i].v);
}
```

Comment: Why would that be any faster to compile?  It's still an array of composite type that's 72000 elements long.

Comment: Would probably not recommend calling `push_back` tens of thousands of times without pre-allocating. `std::vector` has a constructor that can grab all the data from the array (or anything else supporting iterators) in one go.

Comment: I *suspect* the compiler is churning hard on the initialization of a vector from an unusually large inline array of objects with constructor parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way of implementation,

```
Inventory I[] = { {1,30.0},{2,30.0},{3,30.0},{4,30.0 },{5,30.0},{29,30.0 },{30,30.0}};

std::vector<Inventory> inventory_list (I,I+(sizeof(I)/sizeof(Inventory)));
```